# Auto fill out form via URL & POST

Tags: forms, post, get, fill

I've been searching my heart out trying to find a website I frequently used years ago.

The site would let me give it a URL and then it would rewrite the target page for display on its server, let me fill out the page, and then kick out a URL with all the POST parameters when I submitted the page.

For example, let's say I told it to go to Google.com and searched for "blah" - it might kick out a URL like:

http://www.google.com/#q=blah

Does anyone remember what this site is?

Answer (score 0):

The [Tamper Data](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/tamper-data/) extension for Firefox will let you modify POST parameters before sending forms away - it's certainly easier than going to a different page!

Comment: That's very helpful and I've used Tamper Data before, the only thing I don't like about it is that it won't kick out a URL I can easily send to people for auto-filling the page; i.e. it's nice for 1-time things but not automation (if my memory serves me correctly.)